# angular testing promise within a promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have code that works.  But I have no idea how to test it.  A FeeRule has many FeeParameters.

```
angular.module('feeSuitesApp')
  .controller('RootCtrl', [
    'FeeSuiteCrud',
    'FeeSuite',
    'FeeRule',
    'FeeParameter',
    'feeSuites',
    '$scope',
    '$q',
    function(FeeSuiteCrud, FeeSuite, FeeRule, FeeParameter, feeSuites, $scope, $q){

      $scope.feeSuite = feeSuites[0];

      if($scope.feeSuite){
        getFeeRules().then(function(response){
          $scope.feeRules = response;
          $scope.feeRules.forEach(function(feeRule){
            getFeeParameters(feeRule).then(function(response){
                feeRule.parameter_name = response.name
                feeRule.parameter_type = response.parameter_type;
              });
          });
        });
      }

      function getFeeRules(){
        var feeCrud = new FeeSuiteCrud(FeeSuite, FeeRule);
        return feeCrud.get($scope.feeSuite.id);
      }

      function getFeeParameters(feeRule){
        var feeCrud = new FeeSuiteCrud(FeeParameter);
        return feeCrud.get(feeRule.fee_parameter_id);
      }
```

getFeeRules and getFeeParameters return promises from $http.get().

My test:

```
it("gets feeRules and their feeParameters", function(){
  var JSONResponse = {"master":[{"id":30,"fee_suite_id":8,"fee_parameter_id":2,"name":"Discover Fee","multiplier":0.045,"addend":0.0,"order":1,"created_at":"2016-09-27T10:12:26.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-09-27T10:12:26.000-05:00"}]};

  var feeRule = new FeeRule({
      id: 30,
      name: 'Discover Fee',
      fee_suite_id: 8,
      fee_parameter_id: 2,
      multiplier: 0.045,
      addend: 0,
      order: 1
    });

  var feeParameter = new FeeParameter({
    id: 2,
    fee_type_id: 1,
    name: "Discover subtotal",
    value: "discover",
    parameter_type: "currency"
  });

  feeRule.parameter_name = feeParameter.name;
  feeRule.parameter_type = feeParameter.parameter_type;

  $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v3/fee_suites/8?association=fee_rules').respond(JSONResponse);

  JSONResponse = {"id":2,"fee_type_id":1,"name":"Discover subtotal","value":"discover","parameter_type":"currency","created_at":"2016-09-27T10:12:25.000-05:00","updated_at":"2016-09-27T10:12:25.000-05:00"};

  $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v3/fee_parameters/2').respond(JSONResponse);

  $rootScope.$digest();
  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(scope.feeRules).toEqual([feeRule]);
});
```

Doesn't seem the second promise gets resolved as I get the following error:

```
Expected [ FeeRule({ id: 30, name: 'Discover Fee', fee_suite_id: 8,     
fee_parameter_id: 2, multiplier: 0.045, addend: 0, order: 1 }) ] to equal [ 
FeeRule({ id: 30, name: 'Discover Fee', fee_suite_id: 8, fee_parameter_id: 2, 
multiplier: 0.045, addend: 0, order: 1, parameter_name: 'Discover subtotal', 
parameter_type: 'currency' }) ].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it twice it will work

```
$httpBackend.flush();
$httpBackend.flush();
```

and instead of expect get use when('GET',URL)

Comment: expect get means that that url must be called and when is when you are not certain that it will be called or not. Yes you can use either of them again that depends upon the usability